# Create users with passwords in shiny (standard plan)

Tags: r, authentication, shinyapps

We have a shiny application, we have the Standard Plan, so we have private apps and typically one sends user's invitations where they have to create their password.

But since we have the list of users, is there a way (an API or something) to assign passwords while creating users.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They don't have an API for assigning passwords while using Shiny private mode.
The solution was to make it public and creating a login screen.